# List view threshold in reporting services integrated mode in sharepoint

Tags: 2013, reporting-services

In one of my sharepoint sites I have a document library with 7,000 document sets, if I count the files inside there are 21000 files in total.

In the beginning we had some views, but when they growth we had list view threshold issues. What I did was to remove some of those views and use search results webparts to get the results the user wants. For me incrementing the threshold is not a solution because this document library grows fast, (2K per month)

This solved the problem for some time.

However, some users do require to export to excel to do pivots based on this data, the only way I can think of is using reporting services in integrated mode with sharepoint, because I can export reports to excel and then they can do pivots.

The question is, will I have the same threshold problem when I make a report based on list data?

What other options do I have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have 2000 files in the document library/list per month , I dont think its too big . You can create a folder structure inside the sharepoint document library like June2013,July2013..March2014 and start storing the data per month.

For future , You can also think of these folders archived in a separate site collection yearly with different content db and start dumping them . Because large document libraries/lists will impact the performance badly .

Comment: If I use the export to excel function on the main folder, will it export only the items on the root folder? or everything? If I am on a folder, will it export the items in the folder only?

Comment: Good question . I think you need to go inside each folder and get the excel sheet per month.